# how do i check stripe checkout page with web flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-applications, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe in my webApp.
I created a stripe checkout session, firebase function, I can view the page with the url_launcher package, but from there I lose control of what is going on.
So far I am in a loop that requires the stripe api to continually request payment details to understand whether or not they have confirmed the payment.

```
do {
  res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/XXXUUUU"), headers: headers);
  if (res.statusCode != 200)
  throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
  else {
    risultato = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(risultato["payment_status"]);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  }
} while ((risultato["payment_status"] == "unpaid") || !pagamentoInCorso);
```

is there a way to understand it better? a Stream or something more elegant?

Comment: have you successfully implemented stripe on flutter web?

Comment: To obtain the payment outcome with using Checkout Session, it's recommended to use Webhook and listen to `checkout.session.completed` as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ works well on the web.

Comment: can you please share your code for stripe web.
I am not able to do

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ Do I send it to you by email?

Comment: yes that will be great. debjeet.debnath001@gmail.com thank you